# TIBCO BWCE 2.8.2 connecting to Azure for SQL server gives error. Make sure all required jar files exist at folder 'AzureLib' from Local to Cloud

Tags: java, sql-server, tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I am trying to connect from TIBCO BWCE 2.8.2 studio to Azure using ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal. All settings are set as described by TIBCO. However, I still receive the following error:

Make sure all required jar files exist at folder 'AzureLib'

Also the location bwce\2.8\config\design\thirdparty\AzureLib does contain the following jar.

mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8
mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11

Is there another Jar required?

Update:
Receiving now the following error:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user <> in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal). javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: The certificate validation error suggests that you're trying to connect to an SQL Server instance that you built yourself, which uses a self-signed X.509 certificate by default, or that your Java runtime's trust store doesn't contain any Root/ICA certificates that are used to sign AzureSQL certificates. Probably have a read through the [Using encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ssl-encryption) document tree to understand what's happening and how to configure JDBC connection string properties to accomodate.

Comment: You might even need to import certificates into your trust store as per [Configuring the client for encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/configuring-the-client-for-ssl-encryption).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning at the end of the error message it was mentioning "unable to find valid certification path to requested target". Is it referring to cacert location?

Comment: Also trying to figure out which certificate to add. The one used for *.database.windows.net